# Return data in httpresponse for ajax call in Deleteview in django?

Tags: ajax, django

Simply that, I want to send some data after making a delete for a `DeleteView` without the necessity of load a `success_url`, I used to do that within the `form_valid` method in `CreateView`and `UpdateView` but I don't know which method call after making the delete for return a `HttpResponse` with some JSON data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably want to override `delete()` with something like:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic import DeleteView


class MyDeleteView(DeleteView)
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.get_object().delete()
        payload = {'delete': 'ok'}
        return JsonResponse(payload)
```

I suppose it's a bit of a shame that you'll need to duplicate the code that you're overriding.

Check out CCBV if you're unsure... http://ccbv.co.uk/DeleteView/

Disclaimer: I made CCBV.

Comment: @meshy it's one of the few bookmarks I have. Thank you for an awesome tool! Sorry this is in your comments.

Comment: It's not a bit of a shame, it's a shame that you have to Repeat Yourself =(

Answer (score 0):

I have problems with @meshy's answer so I try another implementation. I hope someone will find it helpful :).
When I tried this implementation I got an ImproperlyConfigured Error, that was because I had not defined a success_ulr and the delete() method requires this parameter. So I override form_valid in this way:

```
class MyDeleteView(DeleteView):
     model = #'your model'
     template_name = #'your template path'
    
     def form_valid(self, form):
        self.get_object().delete()
        return HttpResponse('the response that you want')
```

And voila, with this change I was able to give an HttpResponse.